# model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List, but this dictionary requires a model item of type

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dictionary

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 app where users can see an index of projects. I have added another database table called "Applications", which would store application objects that the users create when they apply for a project from the index. 
The Applications model:

```
public class Application
{
    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string CoverLetter { get; set; }

}
```

Where ProjectId and UserId are foreign keys (from dbo.Projects and dbo.AspNetUsers respectively)

Now for the Projects index view I have changed the view model into ApplicationTwoViewModel:

```
 public class ApplicationTwoViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<Project> Model1 { get; set; }
        public Application Model2 { get; set; }
    }
```

The Index.cshtml:

```
@using Leepio.Models
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@model ApplicationTwoViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create" ,"Projects")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Title", "Index", "Projects", new {SortOrder = (ViewBag.SortOrder==null?"Asc":(ViewBag.SortOrder=="Asc"?"Desc":"Asc")), SortBy = "Title"})

        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Application Deadline", "Index", "Projects", new {SortOrder = (ViewBag.SortOrder == null ? "Asc" : (ViewBag.SortOrder == "Asc" ? "Desc" : "Asc")), SortBy = "ApplicationDeadline"}) <br/>
            @Html.ActionLink("Hourly Rate (DKK)", "Index", "Projects", new { SortOrder = (ViewBag.SortOrder == null ? "Asc" : (ViewBag.SortOrder == "Asc" ? "Desc" : "Asc")), SortBy = "HourlyRate" })
        </th>
       <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Skill requirements", "Index", "Projects", new { SortOrder = (ViewBag.SortOrder == null ? "Asc" : (ViewBag.SortOrder == "Asc" ? "Desc" : "Asc")), SortBy = "RequiredSkills" })
        </th>


    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model.Model1) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ApplicationDeadline)<br/>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HourlyRate)
        </td>
       <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RequiredSkills)
        </td>


        <td>

            @if(item.UserId == User.Identity.GetUserId()) 

            {
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Projects", new {id = item.ProjectId})

                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Projects", new {id = item.ProjectId}) 
            }

            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", "Projects", new {id = item.ProjectId}) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Apply", "Index", "Applications", new { id = item.ProjectId }) |
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
@{
    double TotalPage = @ViewBag.TotalPages;
}

<ul class="pagination">
    @for (int i = 1; i <= TotalPage; i++)
    {

        if (i == ViewBag.Page)
        {
            <li class="active"> @Html.ActionLink(i.ToString() + " ", "Index", "Projects", new { SortOrder = (ViewBag.SortOrder == null ? "Asc" : ViewBag.SortOrder), SortBy = (ViewBag.SortBy == null ? "Title" : ViewBag.SortBy), Page = i })</li>
        }
        else
        {
            <li>
                @Html.ActionLink(i.ToString() + " ", "Index", "Projects", new { SortOrder = (ViewBag.SortOrder == null ? "Asc" : ViewBag.SortOrder), SortBy = (ViewBag.SortBy == null ? "Title" : ViewBag.SortBy), Page = i })
            </li>
        }

    }
</ul>
```

And of course I am using Model.Model1 and Model.Model2.

When trying to open the Projects index view I get the following:
**The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Leepio.Models.Project]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Leepio.Models.ApplicationTwoViewModel'.**

ProjectsController:

```
 public ActionResult Index(string SortOrder, string SortBy, string Page)
        {
            ViewBag.SortOrder = SortOrder;
            ViewBag.SortBy = SortBy;
            var projects = db.Projects.ToList();
            var model = new ApplicationTwoViewModel
            {
                Model1 = new List<Project>(projects),
                Model2 = new Application
                {

                    UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId(),
                    ProjectId = 11,
                    CoverLetter = "asdf",
                    ApplicationId = 23,
                }
            };

            //bunch of code I cut out regarding the sorting



        ViewBag.TotalPages =     Math.Ceiling(db.Projects.ToList().Count()/10.0);
        int page = int.Parse(Page == null ? "1" : Page);
        ViewBag.Page = page;
        projects = projects.Skip((page - 1) * 10).Take(10).ToList();
        return View(projects);

    }
```

I've tried initializing Model2 hard coded even though I do not want it this way. What could solve this error? I have a feeling the initialization is off but I am not sure

Comment: This would be downvoted as an answer, so as a comment: try return View(model);

Comment: you are return the wrong model to you view (`return View(projects);`). You need to return the `var model = new ApplicationTwoViewModel` to your view (`return View(model);`)

Comment: In fact, this is so simple I'd call it a typo...

Comment: Actually it did fix the error thank you :) Sometimes other person can just see the issues in an instant when you were searching for it for an hour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your View expects you to accept an instace of your `ApplicationTwoViewModel` class as seen at the top of your `Index.cshtml` View:

```
@model ApplicationTwoViewModel
```

So you just need to create one and pass it in, which should be quite easy as you are already building it within your Controller Action :

```
// Pass the model to your View
return View(model);
```

Since you are explicitly editing it after initializing it, you'll probably want to perform the following before your `return` call and well as ensuring that any other operations (i.e. sorting and filtering) are done to the collection within your Model as well :

```
// Perform your paging at the model level
model.Model1 = model.Model1.Skip((page - 1) * 10).Take(10).ToList();
// Now return it
return View(model);
```

Comment: @crystyxn fyi... you should accept this answer as correct so it can help others in the future